# Decorator chain

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm building a few decorators based on Django's [`@permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator. These decorators simply call the permission_required decorator with different parameters.

For example:

```
def permission_required_ajax(perm):
    return permission_required(perm, raise_exception=True)
```

This works well, and I have several such examples.

The problem is when my decorator accepts no arguments at all:

```
def special_permission():
    return permission_required_ajax('special_permission')
```

This doesn't work. When I decorate a function with the `@special_permission` decorator, I get the following error:

> TypeError: special_permission() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to still *call* your decorator factory:

```
@special_permission()
def function():
    # ...
```

Whatever the expression after the `@` sign produces is used as the decorator; the decorator is called, passing in the function to decorate.

In other words, a decorator is syntactic sugar for:

```
def function():
    # ...
special_permission()(function)
```

If you leave off the `()` call, the function is passed to your wrapper instead.

Alternatively, have your decorator accept the function, and pass it on directly to the decorator produced by the `permission_required_ajax()` call:

```
def special_permission(func):
    return permission_required_ajax('special_permission')(func)
```

and then use it without calling (it is now a decorator, not a decorator factory):

```
@special_permission  # no () call now
def function():
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

### How decorator parameters work

When a decorator has no parameters it gets passed the function/class being decorated. When it has parameters it's first called with the parameters and then whatever is returned is then called with the function/class being decorated.

To recap:

```
# Case 1, no arguments

@foo
def bar(): pass
```

The function `foo` will be called being passed the function `bar` and whatever is returned is then bound to the name `bar`.

```
# Case 2

@foo(1, 2, 3)
def bar(): pass
```

The function `foo` is called passing 1, 2 and 3 as parameters. What `foo` returns is then called passing the `bar` function as argument and what it returns is the bound to the name `bar`.

### For your case

A solution could be just adding parenthesis in the `special_permission` decorator call...

```
@special_permission()  # <-- note the parenthesis
def bar(): ...
```

Alternatively if you don't like adding the parenthesis in the use of the decorator it could be implemented as:

```
def special_permission(f):
    return permission_required_ajax('special_permission')(f)
```